# Having trouble with "if, else" calculation statements

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 with VB.NET, and in class we were assigned this project:

> A procedure should calculate a 2% price increase on all red shirts, but a 1% price increase on all other items. In addition to calculating the price increase, the procedure also should calculate the new price.
>
> You can use the variables `strItemColr`, `strItem`, `decOrigPrice`, `decIncrease`, and `decNewPrice`. Format the original price, price increase, and new price in the `lblOriginal`, `lblIncrease`, and `lblNewPrice` controls, respectively.
>
> Write the Visual Basic code.

If not an answer, just some help please. I'm 16 and I am in the highschool/college class. Our teacher teaches via Skype at the college so I am limited to her help.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with any of the tags. Please can you retag appropriately if you want an answer?

Comment: Please tag homework with the homework tag, so people will give hints instead of full answers that will not help you learn.

Comment: Well I kinda understood the basics so I tried just a simple idea: If strItemColor = "red" Then (I had more but I forgot)

Comment: I always found it easiest to start with the pseudocode when learning. (see here for some good examples: http://www.unf.edu/~broggio/cop2221/2221pseu.htm ) Start out by thinking through the steps you will need to do, write it down, then work on turning that into code.

Answer (score 3):

I would not try to solve the problem, I will just give you hints. Is that fair? And, on purpose, I will use different variable names so it's more clear:

```
'Check the shirt color
If shirtColor = "Red" Then
    increase1 = oldprice1 * 0.02
    newPrice1 = oldPrice1 + increase1
Else
    increase2 = oldPrice2 * 0.01
    newPrice2 = oldPrice2 + increase2
End If
```

Now, to get an A from me, you would have to create an enumeration of the colors instead of teh string or use an existing enumeration like the System.Drawings.Color
Strings are tricky and one spelling mistake or a capitalization of a letter and it's a different color for VB.NET

Comment: tip: set a ' at the end of the first line to get some other colo[u]rs